# how to parsing number multiple of prime numbers c++?

Tags: c++, algorithm, math, primes

i'm very beginner in c++ and trying to learn algorithms.

I'm trying to create a console application that get int number and parsing number multiple of prime numbers. for example get 12 and show 3*2*2.

12 = 3*2*2.

but i have problem with that. i wrote something like this.

```
int prime (int a){ 
    int   i ; 
    if ( a == 2 ){ 
        return   1 ; 
    } 
    for (i=2; i < ((a/2)+1) ;i ++){ 
        if (a%i == 0){ 
            return 0; 
        } 
    } 
    return   1 ; 
 } 

int main() {
    int number;
    int tmp;
    //int primes[];
    cout << "Enter a number:" << endl;
    cin >> number; 
    tmp = number;
    int i = 2;
    for (i; i <= number ; i++){
        if (prime(i)) {
            tmp = number/i;
           cout << tmp <<endl;          
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

my application result for 12 is :
6
4
2
1
1

but i want multiple of prime number,
like 3*2*2 for 12.

how can i change my code to do this....?!

TnX

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code with a debugger or even with simple couts ?

Comment: @DavidKernin A debugger is no good if the algorithm is wrong (it may be hint, though)

Comment: i said im very beginner in c++ and trying to learn something. now i want to solve this problem that happend for me. it is may simple for u. but this is hard for me... :( pls help me to solve that :)

Comment: @DieterLücking a debugger is used to make the algorithm right as far as I know :\ But whatever, he's a beginner I can't ask for that.

Comment: @Amin, what David suggests is that you add some `cout` statements in strategic places in your code, so you see how your algorithm advances while it makes its calculation. This will give you a clue of where it fails.

Comment: Can you describe how you would manually come to the result 12 = 3*2*2 ? Because your program should just take the same steps.

Comment: just print the values on each loop or run the loop manually in the debugger and watch the values. But first, think of the correct algorithm and draw the flowchart to process this will help you understand it easier

Answer (score 1):

I will leave out the *"This can be done better"*-issues. There are 3 issues in your code that make it incorrect:

1. You check if i is prime, but not if it is a divisor. Additional hint: Check the assignment to tmp.
2. You output the quotient instead of the potential factor.
3. You would miss duplicate factors.

Answer (score 1):

In this code:

```
if (prime(i)) {
    tmp = number/i;
    cout << tmp << endl;          
}
```

- At no point do you actually check if `number` is actually divisible by `i`, you just assume it is.
- You only process each number once, so there's no way you could have multiple `2`'s in your result, as you do in your example.
- You print the result of division by `i`, instead of printing `i` itself.

What I suggest, in pseudo-code:

- Starting from 2
- Check whether each number i is

  - Prime and
  - Perfectly divides into the target number
- If it satisfied the above conditions

  - Actually *change* the target number by dividing it by i
  - Print i
  - Keep repeating these steps for the same number i, until it's no longer divisible
- Stop when the target number reaches 1 (or you're past the target number) - if it doesn't reach 1, you're doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

- create array of primes, do not count them all each time. While creating the array check for divisions on primes only and do it up to sqrt(n) . Here you have no error, simply it is much better.
- *checking* for prime dividers for n, for even current prime p you can go to next prime only if the n can be divided by p any more.
- after sucessfull division by p change the checked number for the result of that division.